# GTalk sound notification doesn't always work

Tags: notifications, google-talk

I have a Sony-Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro SK17i with Android 2.3.4 and I tend to use the GTalk app quite a lot. I also use Gmail chat whenever I'm in front of a computer.

Most of the time when I receive a new chat message, it appears both in my phone (triggering a sound notification and a status bar notification, like I've set it to do) and in Gmail (given that I'm on a computer with Gmail open). In these cases I read and answer these messages using Gmail and if I keep chatting in Gmail, my phone remains silent. If there's a break of some ten or fifteen minutes in the conversation, my phone beeps again when my buddy says something.

However, occasionally I just don't get notified of new chats. In these cases neither does my phone beep nor does my browser tab with Gmail show that "Buddy says..." message it normally does. Why is this? I think this happens with new chats only, not after a break in a recent conversation. Is it just a bug I have to live with, or something about which something can be done? Thanks in advance.